# Can I store custom data in $node->data?

Tags: 7, nodes

What is the purpose of $node->data? the [Node object reference](http://drupal.org/node/49768) has $node->date, which used for

> Long date, including timezone data, of when the node was created.

May I use $node->data to store my own temporary variables?

Comment: How temporary is temporary?  Do they need to be saved to the DB at any point?

Comment: In what context are you adding to $node->data? 
I wouldn't recommend using it as a container for any temporary variables, why not store those variables somewhere else, what brings about the necessity for using $node->data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://drupal.org/node/1850170) `$node->data` was used about Drupal 5 and is left there for legacy purposes only. It appears it's only purpose is to prevent "call to undefined property" errors. Do not use it.